# Is there something wrong in my script?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am new to client-side scripting. My problem is I've got a lot of textboxes and I want them to auto-calculate, but so far nothing works. Is there something wrong on my script?

```
function totaltraininghour()
{
var totalhour1=0;
var a1= parseInt(document.getElementById("a1").value);
var b1= parseInt(document.getElementById("b1").value);
var c1= parseInt(document.getElementById("c1").value);
var d1= parseInt(document.getElementById("d1").value);

var totalhour2=0;
var a2= parseInt(document.getElementById("a2").value);
var b2= parseInt(document.getElementById("b2").value);
var c2= parseInt(document.getElementById("c2").value);
var d2= parseInt(document.getElementById("d2").value);

var totalhour3=0;
var a3= parseInt(document.getElementById("a3").value);
var b3= parseInt(document.getElementById("b3").value);
var c3= parseInt(document.getElementById("c3").value);
var d3= parseInt(document.getElementById("d3").value);
var totaltraining=0;

if (a1 >=0)
{
totalhour1 = totalhour1 + a1
}
if (b1>=0)
{
totalhour1 = totalhour1+ b1
}
if (c1>=0)
{
totalhour1 = totalhour1+ c1
}
if (d1>=0)
{
totalhour1 = totalhour1+ d1
}
document.getElementById("txttotalhour1").value = totalhour1

if (a2 >=0)
{
totalhour2 = totalhour2 + a2
}
if (b2>=0)
{
totalhour2 = totalhour2+ b2
}
if (c2>=0)
{
totalhour2 = totalhour2+ c2
}
if (d2>=0)
{
totalhour2 = totalhour2+ d2
}
document.getElementById("txttotalhour2").value = totalhour2

if (a3 >=0)
{
totalhour3 = totalhour2 + a3
}
if (b3>=0) 
{
totalhour3 = totalhour2+ b3
 }
if (c3>=0)
{
totalhour3 = totalhour2+ c3
}
if (d3>=0)
{
totalhour3 = totalhour2+ d3
}
document.getElementById("txttotalhour3").value = totalhour3

totaltraining = totalhour1 + totalhour2 + totalhour3
document.getElementById("txttotaltraininghours").value = totaltraining
 </script>

<asp:TextBox ID="a2" runat="server" Width="100px" onkeyup="totaltraininghour
();"></asp:TextBox> And so on..
```

Comment: I've heard that ASP.NET changes IDs of controls in the generated HTML, which might be your problem. (unfortunately, I don't work with ASP.NET and don't know how to fix it)

Comment: To start with, nearly every Javscript statement ends with a semi-colon which you aren't typing.  Then, have you looked in the error console or debugger console to see what Javascript errors are being reported?

Comment: What's actually happening when you run it? I can tell you that the code as posted has several typos in the calculation of the `totalhour3` field because you say `totalhour3 = totalhour2 + a3` - adding `totalhour2` in instead of `totalhour3`. (You can avoid this issue and make your code neater by saying `totalhour3 += a3`.) @jfriend00: I prefer semicolons on every line, but the code as posted doesn't actually _need_ them explicitly typed in.

Comment: Not sure will it help, but it's a good practice to us semicolons at the end of statement.

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML so we can see what's actually in the web page - not the ASP HTML, but what the browser actually sees?

Comment: when i type on textbox where i put onkeyup event an error shows on the left bottom side saying ive got an error on web page. @jfriend00 sorry sir m just new on this site and i dont know how to do it.  To nnnnn Ill try to renew it based on what you said. (i was trying to add all of the var ex: a1 will be added to totalhour1 + b1 + c1) Im just new on javascripting

Comment: thanks all got it ive got an error on bracketing. I forgot one bracket on ending >_< (im used in vb.net so pardon me) heheheh

Comment: If some of the inputs are empty, or if you type non-numeric data, then `parseInt()` will be returning `NaN` (not-a-number) which won't work in your calculations. (Also, and this is probably not your problem, but anyway: _always_ specify a radix when using `parseInt()`, e.g., `parseInt(someVal, 10)`.) If you're new to JavaSript and don't have any debugging tools (or don't yet know how to use them), try to put several `alert()` statements in your function so that you can perhaps figure out how much of the function gets executed before the error. Or, better look into `console.log()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your IDs are what you think they are. If the controls are within a naming container, the IDs will be mangled. To get around it, have ASP.NET insert the `ClientID`, like this:

```
var a1= parseInt(document.getElementById("<%= a1.ClientID %>").value);
```

Note, unless you fiddle with your web server's settings, this will only work for scripts within .aspx files, not external .js files.

Comment: You can verify if this is the problem or not by viewing the source in your browser. The mangled IDs will be fairly obvious. They are basically constructed by concatenating all the IDs of the container and contained elements with underscores.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a lot shorter way to do what you're trying to do without typing lots of duplicate code:

```
function calcSum(root, num, totalID) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        var val = document.getElementById(root + i).value || "0";
        total += parseInt(val, 10);
    }
    document.getElementById(totalID).value = total;
}

function calc() {
    calcSum("a", 4, "totalhour1");
    calcSum("b", 4, "totalhour2");
    calcSum("c", 4, "totalhour3");
}
```

You can see it working here with all the code visible: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/CZPKM/.  I'd suggest you study how this works so you can vastly simplify your code.

In jQuery, you could do the whole thing like this:

```
$("#calc").click(function() {
    $(".group").each(function() {          // find each group and iterate through them
        var total = 0;
        $(".row", this).each(function() {
            total += parseInt(this.value || "0", 10);   // total all rows in the group
        });
        $(".total", this).val(total);      // store total
    });
});
```

This works with much simpler and more generic HTML you can see here in the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fCLT7/.  This works for an arbitrary number of groups of boxes and an arbitrary number of items in each group.

Comment: Added a generic jQuery option to my answer that totals arbitrary groups of rows, just using class names and a parent div for each group.